# Complex Analysis - How a region's boundary changes under a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to solve this question. I tried plugging in the outer boundary for G (left picture), which is just the unit circle in the complex plane, but I can't simplify it into the form I want $\left(\frac{1}{3}e^{i\theta}\right)$.

$$f(e^{i\theta})=\frac{e^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{3}}{3-e^{i\theta}}=\frac{-2+3e^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{3}e^{i\theta}}{10-3(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}=\frac{-2+3e^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{3}e^{i\theta}}{10-6cos\theta}$$

This is as far as I've been able to simplify this. Is this the right approach? Any help to further simplify is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a transformation like $ f(z)= \frac  {z-1/3}{3-z}$ which is a Mobius transformation it suffices to show that $3$ points of a circle transform to three points of another circle.

That proves that  the whole circle transforms to the other circle.

Pick three points on the boundary of $G$ such as $1,-1,i$ and show that their image is on a boundary circle of $H$.

For example,  $$f(1)= \frac {1-1/3}{3-1} = 1/3$$ which is on the boundary of $H$